# What is the best way to replace smart quotes, smart apostrophe and ellipsis in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, character-encoding

My application allows the user to enter text. When they copy and paste from MS Word, it pastes smart quotes, smart apostrophes and ellipsis. These characters get saved into the database and cause problems. What is the best way to replace these non-UTF-8 characters with normal quotes("), apostrophe(') and periods(...)?

Also, how do you test this functionality? I added a test with these special characters and `# encoding: ISO-8859-1` at the top of the file. The special characters caused the tests stop running: `/home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/redgreen-1.2.2/lib/redgreen.rb:62:in 'sub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)`...Apparently redgreen gem is incompatible with these characters...?

Thanks.

Comment: If these characters were "non-UTF-8" characters you could not save them in a UTF-8 encoded string. No, they are very much Unicode characters! `“` for example is U+201C. They're just not the characters you would like to have (`"` U+0022). The `redgreen` problem is probably exactly because you're using `# encoding: ISO-8859-1` instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can add a before_save method that will convert your text to UTF-8 corresponding characters. if you have just 1 field that might contain non-UTF8 chars then its simple, if you have many fields then it would be better if you dynamically iterate over changed text/string fields and fix UTF-8 problem. Either way you need to use [String#encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode). Here is an example

```
before_save :fix_utf8_encoding

def fix_utf8_encoding
  columns = self.class.columns.select{|col| [:text,:string].include?(col.type)}.map{|col| col.name.to_sym}
  columns.each do |col|
    self[col] = self.self[col].encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace) if self[col].kind_of?(String) #Double checking just in case.
  end
end
private :fix_utf8_encoding
```

And for bonus points you can also check if the field was changed using rails handy changed? helpers before fixing it.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't actually replacing this character: `’`

Comment: This isn't actually replacing the characters with the right ones. Its just stripping out the bad characters. For instance, the Microsoft “ should be replaced by ", but its just removing it.